# How to handle a Value Object referencing an Entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have just started to look into DDD, and is trying to look into some scenarios.

I have a Product (Entity) with a ProductName (Value Object) and a ProductPrice (Value Object). The Product Price then have an amount (decimal) and a Currency.

My issue is regarding the Currency. First I designed this as a Value Object, but it should be possible to add new Currencies to the system, and it should also be possible to list them in some kind of GUI. In other words it seems like I need a repository for Currencies. In my mind this means that Currency should be designed as an Entity.

But, now I have a Value Object (Product Price) referencing an entity (Currency). How should this be handled? My guess (I am not sure) is that I remove the reference to the currency entity inside the Product Price, and instead adds the Id of the Currency (USD, EUR etc). The Currency then becomes its own aggregate.

Is this a valid and preferred design in DDD, or should this be done in some other way?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO :) I am not familiar with DDD, but I think maybe your question will be clearer with a picture summarizing your situation. The overall idea is to [make it easy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for people to understand your problem, so they can eventually help you :) You can use [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make your post as nice as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original DDD book, Evans did discuss the possibility of having values that can reference entities.  (Chapter 5:  "VALUE OBJECTS can even reference ENTITIES")

I think everybody, by and large, has abandoned that practice.  Immutability is too powerful an idea.  Values will normally only reference other values.  Instead of referencing a entity, we include the entity *identifier*.

So the usual solution would be that you model the currency code as a value, and store (copies of) that value in your Price value.

> The Currency then becomes its own aggregate.

I would not expect this to happen.  How does a currency change over time?

What I think you will find is that currency is fairly static: the thing that changes over time is the `CurrencyExchange` -- which currencies are currently listed?  what is the exchange rate today?  What was the exchange rate two years ago?  Which political units prefer this currency as of Thursday?

Currencies are closer in nature to units of measure: feet, inches, meters, pounds, liters seconds.  Meters are a unit of measure in the dimension of length; currency is a unit of measure in the dimension of "money".

> how do you handle that new currencies can be added to the system, and how can you select between currencies in the GUI?

There are two possible answers to that.

If your domain is the authority for which currencies are active in the system, then the currency registry/currency exchange should be a first class entity in your domain model, and manages the process of change to the listed currencies.

If your domain is *not* the authority, then you just cache a copy of the information you get from the authority.  Caches are typically CRUD (PUT, GET, DELETE, maybe PATCH).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I agree that the currency class probably wouldn't change. But, how do you handle that new currencies can be added to the system, and how can you select between currencies in the GUI? 

I guess it is not allowed to have a repository for value types? Do you suggest that currencies are loaded from DB to GUI in a different (simpler) bounded context which handles CRUD only?